# will heroku app go to sleep lead to data lose in the redis addon

Tags: heroku, flask

I build a Flask app in heroku using a free dyno and a free redis addon.

What I noticed is that my data in redis addon will get lost after some period of time.

My question is this: What is the cause of this? To avoid this loss, should I upgrade the dyno or the redis addon?

my server.py:

```
  app = Flask(__name__)
  redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
  redis = redis.from_url(redis_url)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: The free tier of Redis To Go doesn't include persistent storage. If you're filling up the available memory, things will get pushed out and lost. If you're positive that isn't what's happening, you may want to consider contacting Redis To Go.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?